# Receiving response using AFNetworking in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, afnetworking-2

I am new to `AFNetworking` and I am trying to follow the tutorial of Raywenderlich on the same. So I have got this code for `JSON` parsing and I am struggling with converting that to `Swift`. I have tried many tutorials and StackOverflow answers but couldn't find a good explanatory one.

```
- (IBAction)jsonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // 1
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // 2
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // 3
        self.weather = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        self.title = @"JSON Retrieved";
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    // 5
    [operation start];
}
```

So, can any one please help me regarding the basics of parsing data with `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is why you are going with `Objc` in `Swift`. There are many frameworks alternative to `AFNetworking`.

In fact, the same developer has developed the **Network Library** in `Swift` named [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

You can use that framework and get the same response:

Here is the demo example of it!

```
func postWebserviceWithURL(strUrl: String, param: NSDictionary?, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) -> (){

        Alamofire.request(.POST, strUrl, parameters: param as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .Success(let data):
                let json = data as? NSDictionary
                completionHandler(json, nil)
            case .Failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                self.showSingleAlert("app_name", message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So does it provide the same feature as AFNetworking?

Comment: Of course, almost same. You just need to identify the methods of it and you are ready to go! @KamalaDash

Comment: Another question,what are the advantages if we are going for NSUrlSession and default networking classes rather than 3rd party one especially Alamofire/AFNetworking?

Comment: As far as I know, `NSURLSession` is best because it's native. But the problem is that you will receive slow response than other 3rd party libraries. @KamalaDash

Comment: To get it faster you can use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
}` @KamalaDash

Comment: But to get it handy people uses 3rd Party frameworks and there are many advantages of it! @KamalaDash

Comment: Is SwiftyJSON required for implementing Alamofire

Comment: @KamalaDash nope, that's also third party framework to parse JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can easily use AFnetworking library in swift fist of all you need to create Bridging-Header.h file and import AFNetworking.h into your Bridging-Header.h file

and Try this below code into your json method

```
let urlAsString = "<Your json URL in string>"   
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.POST(
            urlAsString,
            parameters: <Parameter>,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
                responseObject: AnyObject!) in
print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
},
failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!
    error: NSError!) in
  }
 )
```