# Can't use AFNetworking on Today Extension

Tags: swift, afnetworking, today-extension

I am struggling to make AFNetworking to work on my Today Extension.

My app is an Objective-c project with cocoapods (0.39.0), in which I started to migrate some stuff to Swift. I successfully made Swift to work with objective-c and I am using AFNetworking in both Swift and Objective-c code.

I added a Today Extension (made in Swift) and when I try to use Swift classes that use AFNetworking, it complains that no "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager" and other AFNetworking related classes couldn't be found.

I tried different solutions to the Podfile, which currently is configured like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

def testing_pods
    pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
    pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', '~> 2.4.0'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'ParseUI'
    pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
    pod 'ParseTwitterUtils'
end

target '***' do

    testing_pods

end

target '***' do

    testing_pods

end

target 'todayExtension' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
end

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        puts "=== #{target.name}"
        if target.name == "AFNetworking"
            puts "Setting AFNetworking Macro AF_APP_EXTENSIONS so that it doesn't use UIApplication in extension."
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                puts "Setting AF_APP_EXTENSIONS macro in config: #{config}"
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS']
            end
        end
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            puts "Setting only_active_arch in config: #{config}"
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

I already deleted all pods and workspace and created them again but the problem still the same.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: First of all clean build  and try to make new bridging-header.h file

Comment: @imjaydeep Thanks but what does it have to do with it? I forgot to mention that the extension is a Swift extension, not objetive-c, I will include it on the main post.

Comment: this link help you to create header file     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627082/how-to-find-path-of-bridging-header-h-swift-xcode

Comment: if you want to get json response through AFnetworking  last answer of this link will be helpful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669707/receiving-response-using-afnetworking-in-swift/34670199#34670199

Answer (score 0):

By default `cocoapods` is creating static libraries for pods, but swift is not supporting static libraries. So to use `cocoapods` with swift you should specify to use dynamic framework. For that include following line to your `Podfile`

```
use_frameworks!
```

For more info go through

https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

**Update**
Also be aware that `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and other `NSURLConnection` related classes are not available in `AFNetworking 3.x`.